Dataset for transformer
I'm making a model using transformer for code generation. I'm confused how to get input and output of data to train decoder only transformer my db is :-
[
    {
      "code": "def bubble_sort(arr):\n    n = len(arr)\n    for i in range(n):\n        for j in range(0, n-i-1):\n            if arr[j] > arr[j+1]:\n                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]\n    return arr",
      "function_name": "bubble_sort",
      "docstring": "Bubble Sort repeatedly steps through the list, compares adjacent elements, and swaps them if they are in the wrong order. This pass through the list is repeated until the list is sorted.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "bubble sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    },
    {
      "code": "def insertion_sort(arr):\n    for i in range(1, len(arr)):\n        key = arr[i]\n        j = i - 1\n        while j >= 0 and key < arr[j]:\n            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]\n            j -= 1\n        arr[j + 1] = key\n    return arr",
      "function_name": "insertion_sort",
      "docstring": "Insertion Sort builds the sorted array  one element at a time by repeatedly picking the next element and inserting it into its correct position in the already sorted part of the array.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "insertion sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    },
    {
      "code": "def selection_sort(arr):\n    for i in range(len(arr)):\n        min_idx = i\n        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):\n            if arr[j] < arr[min_idx]:\n                min_idx = j\n        arr[i], arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]\n    return arr",
      "function_name": "selection_sort",
      "docstring": "Selection Sort repeatedly selects the smallest element from the unsorted part of the list and swaps it with the first unsorted element, effectively growing the sorted portion of the list.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "selection sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    },
    {
      "code": "def merge_sort(arr):\n    if len(arr) > 1:\n        mid = len(arr) // 2\n        L = arr[:mid]\n        R = arr[mid:]\n\n        merge_sort(L)\n        merge_sort(R)\n\n        i = j = k = 0\n\n        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):\n            if L[i] < R[j]:\n                arr[k] = L[i]\n                i += 1\n            else:\n                arr[k] = R[j]\n                j += 1\n            k += 1\n\n        while i < len(L):\n            arr[k] = L[i]\n            i += 1\n            k += 1\n\n        while j < len(R):\n            arr[k] = R[j]\n            j += 1\n            k += 1\n    return arr",
      "function_name": "merge_sort",
      "docstring": "Merge Sort is a divide-and-conquer algorithm that recursively splits the list into halves, sorts each half, and then merges the sorted halves back together.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "merge sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    },
    {
      "code": "def quick_sort(arr):\n    if len(arr) <= 1:\n        return arr\n    else:\n        pivot = arr[len(arr) // 2]\n        left = [x for x in arr if x < pivot]\n        middle = [x for x in arr if x == pivot]\n        right = [x for x in arr if x > pivot]\n        return quick_sort(left) + middle + quick_sort(right)",
      "function_name": "quick_sort",
      "docstring": "Quick Sort is a divide-and-conquer algorithm. It selects a 'pivot' element from the list, partitions the other elements into those less than the pivot and those greater, and then recursively sorts the sub-arrays.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "quick sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    },
    {
      "code": "def heapify(arr, n, i):\n    largest = i\n    left = 2 * i + 1\n    right = 2 * i + 2\n\n    if left < n and arr[left] > arr[largest]:\n        largest = left\n\n    if right < n and arr[right] > arr[largest]:\n        largest = right\n\n    if largest != i:\n        arr[i], arr[largest] = arr[largest], arr[i]\n        heapify(arr, n, largest)\n\n\ndef heap_sort(arr):\n    n = len(arr)\n    for i in range(n // 2 - 1, -1, -1):\n        heapify(arr, n, i)\n\n    for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):\n        arr[i], arr[0] = arr[0], arr[i]\n        heapify(arr, i, 0)\n    return arr",
      "function_name": "heap_sort",
      "docstring": "Heap Sort builds a max heap from the list, then repeatedly extracts the largest element (the root of the heap) and rebuilds the heap, thereby sorting the list.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "heap sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    },
    {
      "code": "def shell_sort(arr):\n    n = len(arr)\n    gap = n // 2\n    while gap > 0:\n        for i in range(gap, n):\n            temp = arr[i]\n            j = i\n            while j >= gap and arr[j - gap] > temp:\n                arr[j] = arr[j - gap]\n                j -= gap\n            arr[j] = temp\n        gap //= 2\n    return arr",
      "function_name": "shell_sort",
      "docstring": "Shell Sort is an extension of Insertion Sort that allows the exchange of far apart elements. It improves on Insertion Sort by comparing elements distant apart, gradually reducing the gap between elements to be compared.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "shell sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    },
    {
      "code": "def counting_sort_for_radix(arr, exp):\n    n = len(arr)\n    output = [0] * n\n    count = [0] * 10\n\n    for i in range(n):\n        index = arr[i] // exp\n        count[index % 10] += 1\n\n    for i in range(1, 10):\n        count[i] += count[i - 1]\n\n    i = n - 1\n    while i >= 0:\n        index = arr[i] // exp\n        output[count[index % 10] - 1] = arr[i]\n        count[index % 10] -= 1\n        i -= 1\n\n    for i in range(len(arr)):\n        arr[i] = output[i]\n\n\ndef radix_sort(arr):\n    max_val = max(arr)\n    exp = 1\n    while max_val // exp > 0:\n        counting_sort_for_radix(arr, exp)\n        exp *= 10\n    return arr",
      "function_name": "radix_sort",
      "docstring": "Radix Sort processes the list digit by digit, starting from the least significant digit to the most significant digit, grouping numbers by each digit's value. It uses Counting Sort as a subroutine to sort based on individual digits.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "radix sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    },
    {
      "code": "def counting_sort(arr):\n    max_val = max(arr)\n    count = [0] * (max_val + 1)\n    output = [0] * len(arr)\n\n    for num in arr:\n        count[num] += 1\n\n    for i in range(1, len(count)):\n        count[i] += count[i - 1]\n\n    for num in reversed(arr):\n        output[count[num] - 1] = num\n        count[num] -= 1\n\n    return output",
      "function_name": "counting_sort",
      "docstring": "Counting Sort counts the occurrences of each unique element in the list, and then uses this count information to place each element in its correct position in the output array.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "counting sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    },
    {
      "code": "def bucket_sort(arr):\n    bucket = []\n    n = len(arr)\n    for i in range(n):\n        bucket.append([])\n\n    for j in arr:\n        index = int(n * j)\n        bucket[index].append(j)\n\n    for i in range(n):\n        bucket[i] = sorted(bucket[i])\n\n    k = 0\n    for i in range(n):\n        for j in range(len(bucket[i])):\n            arr[k] = bucket[i][j]\n            k += 1\n    return arr",
      "function_name": "bucket_sort",
      "docstring": "Bucket Sort divides the elements into several buckets. Each bucket is then sorted individually, either using a different sorting algorithm or by recursively applying Bucket Sort.",
      "language": "python",
      "tags": ["sorting", "algorithm", "bucket sort"],
      "dataset": "sorting_algorithms"
    }
  ]

so it is simple db of sorting algo can someone pls help to change it into input and output form
What should be input and output to pass to model from the db

Let's say that your encoder block accepts a 3d tensor (n, seq_len, features)

n corresponds to observations
seq_len typically corresponds to the length of the sentence / sequence of text
features typically represent the embedding size

Each dict() you have here would be a singe observation (n axis);
I would suggest to use code in the decoder block, since you want to generate text (code) as an output.
Then it gets a bit tricky. You have distinct categories: function_name, docstring, language, tags, dataset, each of them corresponds to different types of data (e.g. categorical, plain text, etc.) Figuring out how to efficiently use these data differences might take some creativity. A more simple approach seems to be (1) to treat them all as a single string (single embedding for all categories), or (2) use 5 different embeddings for each of the 5 categories, but maintain the same dimensionality (e.g. 512 for every subword unit/ word). This will give you either 1 embedding (long_seq_len, embed_size (e.g. 512)) in case (1), or 5 embeddings (seq_len_i, embed_size), where seq_len_i would be different for each of 5. You could then just concatenate them along seq_len_i axis to get (sum_of_seq_len, embed_size) in case (2).
This way, you get a singe observation (1, long_seq_len, embed_size) in case (1), or (1, sum_of_seq_len, embed_size) in case of (2) for your encoder block.
For the decoder you shall use code row, treat it in the similar manner: create an embedding of the same size as before (again, for simplicity. e.g. 512), and get a data block (1, seq_len, 512).

But how to create the prompts as input as i saw somewhere they were creating different prompts for same code so woudnt it be redundant to do so.

I think you just follow this general rule, concat the data you want to use on the seq_len axis. The docstring in your data is textual, so it pretty much seems like a prompt itself.
